# Triangle is cut into half with ratio 2:1, what is the line segment length cutting the triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

The triangle ABC is cut into two parts by a line DE, which is  parallel to the base AB of the triangle, so that the area of the upper triangle is half of the area of the trapezoid ABED below. How long is the segment DE when the base is 2.00?

**The answer is given at the end of the book, which is 1,55** but I want to learn this. There must be some "more efficient" way than just by iterating the lengths of sides to get the area of half of the bottom, which is very worksome...

[image: Triangle for the question]

Comment: You mean $1.15$ instead of $1.55$, don't you?

Comment: No, it is printed "1.55" at the end of the solution sheet. Probably it is a mistake by the author then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we scale the sides of any triangle by a factor of $k$, the area changes by a factor of $k^2$. In your case, the triangle with base $DE$ has area that is one third of the original triangle.

Therefore, we get $k^2=\frac{1}{3}\implies k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

Multiply that by $2$ to get the result.

Comment: ... which gives $1.15$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe That's right. In fact, I upvoted your comment.

Comment: Elegant answer of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem is the following. Let $DE=x$ and note that the triangle can vary its form having base $a$ and height arbitrary $h$ so we take a rectangle triangle having  legs $a$ and $h$ and form the function $f(t)=\dfrac{at}{h}$. It follows
$$\int_0^b\dfrac{at}{h}dt=\frac13\cdot\frac{ah}{2}\iff b^2=\frac{h^2}{3}$$ and because  $\dfrac xb=\dfrac ah$ we get $x=\dfrac{a}{\sqrt3}$.

Thus for the value $a=2$ we have $x=1.154700$